# IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: arcpy, cursor, indentationerror

I am getting the IndentationError in arcpy. I understand this is covered elsewhere but none of the tips appear to be working, I cannot figure out the error.

Here is my code;

```
def getCoords(self):

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(self.inFC, ['SHAPE@XY']) as rows:
        self.coordList = [r[0] for r in rows]
```

I am getting the error at the line that starts "with". I am using Notepad++ and have changed tabs to spaces (4) in preferences. I have deleted and re-written my code a number of times to ensure no erroneous spaces, however I am still getting this error.

self.coordList is created when the class is initialised;

```
def __init__(self, inFC, buffDist, sector): #Must have a set of points and a value to buffer these by. Also, sector.

    self.inFC = inFC
    self.buffDist = buffDist
    self.sector = sector
    self.coordList = []
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code (the line where the failure occurs)?  Something like `for row in rows:`, and then the line after that, all indented correctly

Comment: I recommend using IDLE rather than Notepad++ for editing Python code with ArcPy.  It gets installed by default, and takes care of indentation for you.  Simply hit Enter after a line that ends in a **`:`** and you will see that happen.

Comment: sometimes you will get an error like this if some of your indentation is done with spaces and some with tabs.

Comment: Do you really have a blank line between your method definition (`def getCoords`) and the body (`with ...`)? I'm not sure how Notepad++ operates, but *some* text editors will eliminate 'extra' whitespace at the end of lines if there is no other characters following it. I'd recommend removing that blank line if it is there.

Comment: Notepad++ has a 'Trim trailing and save' macro, which I believe has the shortcut of ctrl+shift+S. I've changed mine to call this for ctrl+S though, so every time I save, all trailing whitespace is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation errors are nearly always due to a mix of tabs and spaces. Use the Show All Characters button in Notepad++ to check each line is indented in the same way.

[image]

Even if you have checked Replace by space in the Tab Settings menu, you still have to do a manual replacement, especially if you have pasted in code from elsewhere.
Go to Edit > Blank Operations > TAB to Space

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the error that is being thrown by the code snippet that you have presented is more likely to be:

> unexpected EOF while parsing

To reproduce that I used the Python code below:

```
def test_function():

    with open(r"C:\Temp\test.txt", "r") as f:
```

It occurs because, as @Vince commented, there needs to be something on the next line.  For testing purposes we can use `pass`.  Try running the above to see the error (`C:\Temp\test.txt` must exist), and then the following to see the error disappear.

```
def test_function():

    with open(r"C:\Temp\test.txt", "r") as f:

        pass
```

What you are seeing is a pure Python rather than ArcPy problem.

Comment: Apologies, I should have included the line below (now included). I do have a line beneath "with", but still the same error.